# PHP: know if the function's return value will be used or discarded

Tags: php

Given the function

```
function sum( $a, $b )
{
   echo $a + $b;
   return $a + $b;
}
```

It's return value may be used...

```
$c = sum( 2, 3 );
otherFunction( sum( 4, 5 ) );
```

...or just discarded.

```
sum( 6, 7 );
```

Is there a way to know from the code inside `sum()` if upon function termination the return value will be used (assigned to a variable/expression or passed to another function) or discarded?

Comment: no, why would you even want to do that?!

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve? i.e. where / why is it important that you know whether is was accepted or not.? imo, this is an XY issue.

Comment: honestly I'm curious if PHP has such feature. Taking the example in the question `sum` may **echo** the result if the return value is discarded or stay silent if the result is used...

Comment: You need to tell the code inside sum() whether to echo or return.  Maybe pass an argument?

Comment: @AbraCadaver of course I was trying to avoid the extra argument

Comment: Personally I always return and never echo, for most simple functions that is.

Comment: Keep it simple: Let the responsibility to echoing os passing ahead to the functions that are using sum.

Comment: that was just an example to introduce the question *Is there a way to know from the code inside a function if upon function termination the return value will be used or discarded?*. I'm not facing any problem. It's not an XY issue. Just asking if a given feature is available in PHP. I apologize if such question is inappropriate for SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not.

There are languages that let you detect the calling context of a function (e.g. Perl has `wantarray` which will tell you not only if the return value is being assigned, but whether it's expected to be a scalar or list value).  But they are the exception; most have no such feature, and PHP is in that camp.

Your function has to just return the value it means to return and leave it up to the caller to either use that returned value or not.